# Why my M25P16 SPI Flash is not responding to Read ID command

Tags: spi, flash

I have interfaced [M25P16](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/.../m25p16.pdf) with PIC32MX795F512L. MISO and CS is pulled up to VCC with 10k resistor. 
I am sending the 0x9f (MSB first) command for reading device ID and after that 20 dummy bytes are transmitted for generating clock for receiving bytes. But I'm getting unexpected noise pulses on MISO pin as shown in image below.

[image: waveform]
I have selected clock mode as 1 (i.e. CPOL = 0  and CPHA = 1). I'm sampling input in middle of clock.
One more thing HOLD# and W# are directly connected to VCC(3.3 V). Do I need to make changes in W# and HOLD# states?

Comment: You say you've set your clock mode to 1, but your scope traces show your data is clocked on the rising edge (so it's mode 0, CPOL & CPHA=0). Was this a typo? And what is the state of the HOLD pin?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm sampling input in middle of clock"?

Comment: @Cheibriados : Yes that was typo, sorry. But I tried with all 4 modes. Everytime negative result.

Comment: @JimmyB : SPI Data Input Sample phase in middle.

Comment: @Cheibriados : But the thing is in other modes I'm not getting noise pulses also.

Comment: What's your SPI clock speed?

Comment: I'm setting clock frequency to 1MHz.

Comment: Maybe duplicate, but if not, some helpful suggestions in the answer [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97659/flash-memory-spi-miso-line-unresponsive-using-pic)

Comment: Not sure where exactly you set your sampling points, but I think you really should sample at the clock edges just as the chips do.

Comment: I read [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97659/flash-memory-spi-miso-line-unresponsive-using-pic). and followed all modifications in my design too. Then what I'm getting is the above case.

Comment: @JimmyB: I tested same code in loopback mode with other SPI channel of same controller. It was working perfectly at that time. I just sent one byte from Master SPI to slave SPI channel and then slave respond to master SPI.

Comment: Have you tried any other commands? Can you perform a write and then read to verify that you can communicate with the flash chip? It's possible that either you fried it or you've got a bad chip, and verifying it with a new or known-good chip would help.

Comment: I'm not able to read/write. I even tried by changing the M25P16 chip. But second chip also responding same as first one. I connected HOLD# and W# to VCC. Is it correct?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to look at the signals? And how about Vcc, do you have adequate decoupling?

Comment: Yes.I tested it on oscilloscope too, but not getting result. Also I have connected Dcaps between VCC and GND.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your code and maybe also a scope trace? I think @mjh2007 is on the right track in that there may be either pin contention or problems in the setup, but we need more info. Moreover, problems with noise and voltage levels may not show up in the logic analyzer output, but will be immediately obvious in a scope trace.

Comment: Perhaps modify your software not to drive the chip select, and configure a pull up resistor on MISO.  Do you see anything happen on MISO with the scope?  It *should* just stay high...

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yes. Now I tried this too. My MISO is pulled up and is continuously high

Answer (score 2):

I not sure if this problem was solved, I had exactly the same problem as you two days ago and nothing on the internet I found helped, it seems everyone had a unique problem expect yours...

After 2 days of debugging I found the solution, its very simple.. the chip 3.3V tolerant (power supply and input signals.. they NOT 5V tolerant!), if your input signals is NOT 3.3v i.e (Input CLOCK, CS, MOSI, MISO) the flash chip will not respond.

All I did was use a level translation using a 74HC4050, it is always a good test to make sure communication is 100% by sending a device id request to the chip, then proceeding to working with memory writes and reads.

Funny, after two days of exceeding the input signals with a 5V input the chip still works, maybe internally some sort of (undocumented) protection clamp was active.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah... WE have to follow I/O voltage ratings as per standard datasheet, and I was following same. But don't know why It's not working. After modifying some part of circuit, it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the flash memory is trying to respond to the command, but can't. I would check that there are no conflicts with the MISO pin. Make sure that some other peripheral on your microcontroller isn't using the MISO pin, that the MISO pin is not shorted to another pin, and make sure there is not a problem with any other device on the SPI bus.

Comment: I agree with you. But as per my knowledge no other device is using my SPI peripheral pins. PIC32MX795F512L have 4 SPI channels. from that I'm using SPI3 as master and SPI4 as slave. I tested by sending few bytes from master SPI to slave channel and vice versa, at that time **it was transferring correctly** with **no error**. So I think SPI peripheral is fine. am I right?